# When converting matrix to dist object, first row disappears

Tags: r, csv, matrix

I need to convert two (lower triangle + diagonal values only) `.csv` distance matrices to dist `objects` in order to perform a `Mantel test`. Although as.dist(matrixname) appears to work, my first row disappears so that the distance `matrix` is offset by one row. FYI, my column and row labels are three-letter codes rather than numbers - Could this be an issue?

I've used the following commands:

`fst <- read.csv("fst.csv",row.names=1)
fst.dist <- as.dist(fst)`

When I read in the .csv file, everything looks fine.

Comment: Have you tried with `diag=TRUE`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `diag=TRUE` to your `as.dist` call.

For example:

```
d <- read.table(text='0 1 2 
                      1 0 3
                      2 3 0')

as.dist(d)

#    V1 V2
# V2  1   
# V3  2  3

as.dist(d, diag=TRUE)

#    V1 V2 V3
# V1  0      
# V2  1  0   
# V3  2  3  0
```